# Does do() function from (dplyr package) automatically show a progress bar in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

When I call `do()` function in `R` on a grouped table, then it shows me a progress bar as below. However, I do not recall installing anything related to the progress bar package. Is this functionality inbuilt in `do()` function?

```
|==============                                                | 40% ~2m remaining
```

Comment: It’s built into the function, and is only shown when dplyr thinks that this operation is going to take long. [The documentation mentions it](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/do.html), albeit in passing.

Comment: @KonradRudolph : Thanks for your answer. True that the documentation mentions it briefly. It answers my question on why I keep seeing the progress bar. Cheers.

Comment: Another reference (with the ability to *disable* it) can be found here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/progress_estimated.html